# Access source code from a shared kotlin project - Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, shared-libraries

I am attempting to understand how I can create a dependency in gradle so that its code can be shared across multiple projects I have searched around but haven't been able to fully understand how this works

I am using Kotlin and Gradle and my understanding is that the best approach (one that I like as well) is to create a separate project that creates a jar, which I can then import (I can later upload this to nexus)

**ProjectA**

SharedProjectLib

In SharedProjectLib I have the following settings

```
`settings.gradle.kts

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version "0.5.0"
}

rootProject.name = "SharedProjectLib"
in build.gradle.kts I have


plugins {
    `java-library`
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.9.0"
}


group = "me.user"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(8)
        withJava()
        testRuns.named("test") {
            executionTask.configure {
                useJUnitPlatform()
            }
        }
    }

    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

After building this project, I have a jar file, which I have moved into the lib folder of ProjectA Now, in the settings I have tried the following build.gradle

```
`plugins {
    id 'java'
    ...


dependencies {
    implementation files('lib/SharedProjectLib-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    ...`
```

Thank you

These settings don't work and there are so many configurations I found online but not sure how to apply them. How can I set ProjectA so that I can access a simple data class object from SharedProjectLib

I am trying to create a library that contains common code (classes, methods) that can be imported and shared by other projects

Answer (score 0):

Jar files might not contain every dependency that your sub-project might be using!

This is what the [`Settings.include`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api.initialization/-settings/include.html) method is for in settings scripts (i.e. `settings.gradle.kts`/`settings.gradle` files), which is [documented in the Adding sub-projects section of the Creating a Basic Multi-Project Build document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:adding_subprojects). You would then pass a project path:

```
// root settings.gradle.kts in your project:

// For example, if your library is in /common
include(":common")
include(":common:another-project")
```

You can then [declare a dependency on the library project(s)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies) in the `dependencies` scope with the relevant Gradle configuration (e.g. `implementation`, `api`, `compileOnly`):

```
// app/build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
  implementation(project(":common"))
  implementation(project(":common:another-project"))
}
```

(As a bonus, you can make it type-safe by [opting into the type-safe project dependencies feature preview (requires Gradle 7+)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:type-safe-project-accessors):)

```
// /settings.gradle.kts
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

// app/build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
  implementation(projects.common)
  implementation(projects.common.anotherProject)
}
```

For more info, consider checking out the Gradle docs:

- [Structuring and Building a Software Component with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)
- [Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)
- [Structuring Large Projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/structuring_software_products.html)